# http.get and ISO-8859-1 encoded responses

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I'm about to write a RSS-feed fetcher and stuck with some charset problems.

Loading and parsing the feed was quite easy compared to the encoding.
I'm loading the feed with `http.get` and I'm putting the chunks together on every data event.
Later I'm parsing the whole string with the npm-lib `feedparser` which works fine with the given string.

Sadly I'm used to functions like `utf8_encode()` in php and I'm missing them in node.js so I'm stuck with using Iconv which is currently not doing what I want.

Without encoding there are several utf8 ?-icons for wrong charset, with iconv, the string is parsed wrong :/

Currently I'm encoding every string seperatedly:

```
//var encoding ≈ ISO-8859-1 etc. (Is the right one, checked with docs etc.)
// Shortend version

var iconv = new Iconv(encoding, 'UTF-8');

parser.on('article', function(article){
    var object = {
        title : iconv.convert(article.title).toString('UTF-8'),
        description : iconv.convert(article.summary).toString('UTF-8')
    }
    Articles.push(object);
});
```

Should I start encoding with data-buffers or later with the complete string?

Thank you!

PS: Encoding is determined with parsing the head of xml

How about a module which makes encoding in node.js easier?

Comment: Is what you have not working?

Comment: I cannot get iconv encoding right

Comment: So the article objects are not encoded correctly and instead contain garbage? And could you show the feed?

Comment: yepp, the script is working fine, but the encodet characters (ü,ö,ä etc.) are wrong

Comment: Could you give us the output of 'console.log(new Buffer(article.title));' for one of the titles that is being encoded wrong?

Comment: iconv is convertig to `fï¿½nf` instead of fünf | source is http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss

Comment: Buffers are looking like this (shortend by node):

<Buffer 42 61 6c 6c 20 61 75 66 20 57 69 65 6e 65 72 20 48 6f 66 62 75 72 67 3a 20 45 6d 70 ef bf bd 72 75 6e 67 20 ef bf bd 62 65 72 20 74 61 6e 7a 65 6e 64 65 ...>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably hitting the same problem described on https://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/b2603afa31aada9c.

The solution seems to be to set the response encoding to binary before processing the Buffer with Iconv.

The relevant bit is

> set response.setEncoding('binary') and aggregate the chunks into a buffer before calling Iconv.convert(). Note that encoding=binary means your data callback will receive Buffer objects, not strings.

---

*Updated*: *this was my initial response*

Are you sure that the feed you are receiving has been encoded correctly?

I can see two possible errors:

1. the feed is being sent with Latin-1-encoded data, but with a `Content-Type` that states `charset=UTF-8`.
2. the feed is being sent with UTF-8-encoded data but the `Content-Type` header does not state anything, defaulting to ASCII.

You should check the content of your feed and the sent headers with some utility like Wireshark or cURL.

Comment: im working with moe- the source is http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the content is ISO-8859-1 encoded. Content-Header  and the header of the xml-file match.

Comment: Indeed it seems correctly encoded. I updated my answer to suggest another solution.

Comment: Wow, it's working! But I have a question about the buffer. The buffer needs a size, currently it's set to 10mb (like in your link), should I leave it like that, or is there a better way handling the buffer size?

Comment: Buffers are strange beasts. Just use the default values, they will not waste memory, don't worry. If you want to reduce its size, you can do it but remember that buffers cannot be increased in size so, whatever size you choose, make sure that it will fit every possible RSS feed you will receive.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is probably with the way that you are storing the data before you are passing it to feedparser. It is hard to say without seeing your data event handler, but I'm going to guess that you are doing something like this:

```
values = '';
stream.on('data', function(chunk){
  values += chunk;
});
```

Is that right?

The issue is that in this case, chunk is a buffer, and by using '+' to append them all together, you implicitly convert the buffer to a string.

Looking into it further, you should really be doing the iconv conversion on the whole feed, before running it through feedparser, because feedparser is likely not aware of other encodings.

Try something like this:

```
var iconv = new Iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF8');
var chunks = [];
var totallength = 0;
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
  totallength += chunk.length;
});
stream.on('end', function() {
  var results = new Buffer(totallength);
  var pos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    chunks[i].copy(results, pos);
    pos += chunks[i].length;
  }
  var converted = iconv.convert(results);
  parser.parseString(converted.toString('utf8'));
});
```