# nodejs encoding using request

Tags: node.js, encoding

I am trying to get the correct encoding with request.

```
request.get({
    "uri":'http://www.bold.dk/tv/',
    "encoding": "text/html;charset='charset=utf-8'"
  },
  function(err, resp, body){    
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

No matter what I do the encoding of the danish chars are not right.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You've mixed `encoding` with the `content-type` header -- e.g.: `"encoding": "utf-8"`. But, the page is encoded in `ISO-8859-1` rather than `UTF-8`. For that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915404/http-get-and-iso-8859-1-encoded-responses.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Im using notepad++

Comment: @hippie: Now this is a long shot, but sometimes I have the same issue with german letters. And everytime that happens it is because my Notepad++ saves my scripts as ANSI and not UTF-8. If it in ANSI, try switching it to UTF-8. It is an option in your Notepad++ under Coding (dunno what the english term there is, because I am using the german version)

Comment: Mixed it up, tried alot of things. I tried both and nothing is working.

Comment: @Amverlambs: Just tried that, didnt work.

Comment: @Amberlamps : Your are right about the Notepad++ has issues. Just ran it in cmd. Works fine. Thanks all for helping out

Comment: if you use `http.request()` and call `request.setHeader('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8)` that should change the HTTP Header, and a conforming web server should deliver in UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your trouble is in `'Accept-Encoding'` header.
Let's say you have Headers like `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'`

If it's so, you have 2 ways to fixing this:

1. Remove this Header
2. Use the following code to unzip the data:

   ```
   const req = request(options, res => {
       let buffers = []
       let bufferLength = 0
       let strings = []

       const getData = chunk => {
           if (!Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
               strings.push(chunk)
           } else if (chunk.length) {
               bufferLength += chunk.length
               buffers.push(chunk)
           }
       }

       const endData = () => {
           let response = {code: 200, body: ''}
           if (bufferLength) {
               response.body = Buffer.concat(buffers, bufferLength)
               if (options.encoding !== null) {
                   response.body = response.body.toString(options.encoding)
               }
               buffers = []
               bufferLength = 0
           } else if (strings.length) {
               if (options.encoding === 'utf8' && strings[0].length > 0 && strings[0][0] === '\uFEFF') {
                   strings[0] = strings[0].substring(1)
               }
               response.body = strings.join('')
           }
           console.log('response', response)
       };

       switch (res.headers['content-encoding']) {
           // or, just use zlib.createUnzip() to handle both cases
           case 'gzip':
               res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
                   .on('data', getData)
                   .on('end', endData)
               break;
           case 'deflate':
               res.pipe(zlib.createInflate())
                   .on('data', getData)
                   .on('end', endData)
               break;
           default:
               res.pipe(zlib.createInflate())
                   .on('data', getData)
                   .on('end', endData)
               break;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Removing 'accept-encoding' from the request header fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

You can use iconv (lite) to convert this. You also need to tell request not to actively set the encoding to the default of UTF-8 by setting the encoding property to null. Therefore you should do:

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
request.get({
    uri:'http://www.bold.dk/tv/',
    encoding: null
  },
  function(err, resp, body){    
    var bodyWithCorrectEncoding = iconv.decode(body, 'iso-8859-1');
    console.log(bodyWithCorrectEncoding);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, with `request v2.88.0`.

Refer to woolfi makkinan's answer, I got a simple way to solve the problem.

```js
request.get({
    "uri": 'http://www.bold.dk/tv/',
    "encoding": "text/html;charset='charset=utf-8'",
    "gzip": true // notice this config
  },
  function(err, resp, body){    
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

Add `gzip: true` to `request` options, `request` will deal with gzip, and then blob can convert to string correctly.
​