# npm request module encoding

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm making the following request:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(url, function(error, response, html) {

  if (!error) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    console.log(html);
}
```

And I am only getting [jewel characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VZBN.png). 
How can I get the correct output?

### Solution:

I followed the suggestion on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040643/nodejs-encoding-using-request).

```
app.get('/fetchdata', function(req, res) {
  request({
    uri: urlSource,
    //null for encoding to avoid default utf-8
    encoding: null
  }, function(error, response, html) {
    //using iconv to decode to iso-8859 /latin1
      html = iconv.decode(html, 'iso-8859-1');
    console.log(html);
    ...
```

Comment: do you use utf-8 in all your files? If not, consider it.

Comment: @Gavriel thanks for your answer. I am now considering a middleware like this: 
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  next();
});`

Still no joy, got this error now: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.