# Request returning unicode replacement character

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module to load a webpage, I notice that for he UK pound symbol `£` I sometimes get back the unicode replacement character `\uFFFD`.

An example URL that I'm parsing is this Amazon UK page: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00R3P1NSI/ref=s9_newr_gw_d38_g351_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0Q529EEEZWKPCVQBRHT9&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455333147&pf_rd_i=468294

I'm also using the [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) module to decode using the charset returned in the response header:

```
request(urlEntry.url, function(err, response, html) {
    const contType = response.headers['content-type'];
    const charset = contType.substring(contType.indexOf('charset=') + 8, contType.length);

    const encBody = iconv.decode(html, charset);
...
```

But this doesn't seem to be helping. I've also tried decoding the response HTML as `UTF-8`.

How can I avoid this Unicode replacement char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the Amazon webpage is encoded in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. This is what causes the Unicode replacement character. You can check this in the response headers. I used `curl -i`.

Secondly, the README for requests says:

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default).

It is UTF-8 by default... and (after a little experimentation) we find that it sadly it doesn't support ISO-8859-1. However, if we set the encoding to null we can then decode the resulting Buffer using iconv-lite.

Here is a sample program.

```
var request = require('request');
var iconvlite = require('iconv-lite');

var url = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00R3P1NSI/ref=s9_newr_gw_d38_g351_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0Q529EEEZWKPCVQBRHT9&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455333147&pf_rd_i=468294";

request({url: url, encoding: null}, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       var encoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
       var content = iconvlite.decode(body, encoding);
       console.log(content);
   }

});
```

This question is somewhat related, and I used it whilst figuring this out:
[http.get and ISO-8859-1 encoded responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915404/http-get-and-iso-8859-1-encoded-responses)

Comment: Thanks Colin. The combination of your answer with what I've currently done got everything working as I'd like. Cheers.